# IF = Row Header - Excel formula required

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula, rows

The red rectangle area is what I would like the formula to achieve.

The top blue row is the number of the leaflet the customer requires.
Each row below that has a customer name and address (out of view on the left hand side).
Some customers want more than one leaflet so would need something like 14(x2) as in the image.

There are over 700 customers (rows).

Thanks for your help.

Please find a link to my screenshot here:
http://s638.photobucket.com/user/generalsoulfly/media/Screenshot.jpg.html

Answer (score 0):

I would create a helper column for each of the headers: 1 through 20.  Then you can write a formula that basically says if it's greater than 1, you will append a (xQuantity) value, otherwise, just output the header.  Finally, you can concatenate all these helpers together with `=CONCATENATE`.  This is easier to show in pictures below. Note, be mindful of your absolute vs. relative references and your spaces.

[image: Excel 01]

[image: Excel 02]

[image: Excel 03]

Of course, you could tweak the formula for the last column so that there is no trailing comma.  Alternatively, you could just strip the comma off the Concatenate column with `=LEFT(concatCell, LEN(concatCell)-1)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot JasonAizkalns, this works brilliantly. The only thing is the last bit of information on how to get rid of the last comma on the Concatenate column. =LEFT(concatCell, LEN(concatCell)-1) Could you just show me how I can fit that into the formula as I can't figure it out. Many thanks.

Comment: @Mark In this example, just use another column (in this example, column `M`).  In that cell, type `=LEFT(L3, LEN(L3)-1)`.  Then drag that formula down and you should strip off the last comma.  Alternatively, you could modify the formulas in `column J`.  Keep in mind that SO is not a "code writing" service; it is preferable to say "I have tried this, and this" vs. "I can't figure it out" - best of luck.